# getting error in Merge PDF's In C# using Itextsharpdll

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

when i am trying the merge the PDF's in C# using itextsharp, i used below code It worked for 2 or 3 times. But after that Output file is creating with 0 kb, when i am trying open file it showing file is in use or already open by other.  Please help if missed anything Thanks in Adavance.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
PdfImportedPage page = null;
FileStream stream = null;
Document pdfDoc = null;
try
{
    using(pdfDoc = new Document())
        stream = new FileStream(targetPDF, FileMode.Create);

    {
        using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream))
        {
            pdfDoc.Open();
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                    pdf.AddPage(page);
                }
                pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (reader != null)
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWMV.png)

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the exception in the `catch` block, are you sure your code isn't throwing an error and you're just not seeing it?

Comment: Yes i am just checking Output PDF file, When i am trying to open Output PDF file it showing like file is  already open or using by another application.

Comment: I understand the output file is empty, but I'm asking if you've stepped through this code in the debugger and checked to see if an exception is being thrown.  If so, the exception will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The code you shared in the question does not even compile...

Comment: `using(pdfDoc = new Document())` : The `{` is one line **after** `stream = new FileStream(targetPDF, FileMode.Create);` instead of before it. (I only formatted the code in your question, I didn't reorder it or anything like that ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happen with your code but I can give a function (I'm using in my project working 100%) that merge a list of file

```
    private bool MergePDFs(IEnumerable<string> fileNames, string targetPdf)
    {
        bool merged = true;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
            PdfReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                document.Open();
                foreach (string file in fileNames)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    reader = new PdfReader(file);
                    pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                merged = false;
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (document != null)
                {
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }
```

- so for fileNames : you give the list of your files (construct a list
  from your folder by listing files)
- targetPdf is the outPut file name